# Recover dynamic form data in Java PrimeFaces Extension

Tags: jsf, primefaces-extensions

my job consists in recovering from a web service a form already filled; modify it with the transmit, the problem that the loop that I made gets the model before the modification I want to know how to recover the form after the modification

```
List<ModeleForm> modeles = new ArrayList<ModeleForm>();
for (DynaFormControl dynaFormControl : model.getControls()) {
    System.out.println("recup");
    modeles.add((ModeleForm) dynaFormControl.getData());
}
```

I tried this loop but it retrieves only the initial values.

```
  model = new DynaFormModel();
    try {

        String url = "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data?taskId=" + idTask + "";
        Representation respons = getClientResource(url).get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(respons.getText());

        if (object != null) {

            JSONArray formProperties = object.getJSONArray("formProperties");
            DynaFormLabel labels[] = new DynaFormLabel[0];
            DynaFormControl labels2[] = new DynaFormControl[0];

            labels = new DynaFormLabel[formProperties.length()];
            labels2 = new DynaFormControl[formProperties.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < (formProperties.length()); i++) {
                DynaFormRow row = model.createRegularRow();
                boolean required = Boolean.valueOf(formProperties.getJSONObject(i).getString("required"));
                labels[i] = row.addLabel(formProperties.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                labels2[i] = row.addControl(new ModeleForm(formProperties.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"), formProperties.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), formProperties.getJSONObject(i).getString("value"), required), getType(formProperties.getJSONObject(i).getString("type")));
                labels[i].setForControl(labels2[i]);

            }
            labels = null;
            labels2 = null;

        }
        object = null;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DemandeGeneraleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DemandeGeneraleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DemandeGeneraleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("apres la fct create");
    return model;
}
```

this code create the modele

```
  <h:panelGroup id="dynaFormGroup"> 

                    <pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{tachesController.createForm()}" var="data" 
                                 autoSubmit="true" widgetVar="dynaForm"  >


                        <ui:include  src="colsAddM2.xhtml"/>

                    </pe:dynaForm>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

my page .xhtml which displays the dynamic form

Comment: Can you give us more details please

Comment: Yes, please some [mcve] And please don't use the [java] tag on questions that cannot be reproduced in a plain jdk without additional jars.

Comment: I appreciate that you a responsive and enhancing your question, but it still seemes quite unclear. Please explain in detail what the expected and observed behaviour is like and precisely follow the hints about [mcve].

Comment: Yes, all the json parts are most likely not relevant for [mcve]